# how to print the session array variable values in another page in php

Tags: php

this is the program to print the all subject name which are the field name of the student table.i stored the all subject name into an array and i have to print that array values in that another page.so i stored that array into session variable but while to print that array in next page it print only as "Array".

```
<?php

session_start();
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");  
mysql_select_db("cse",$con);

$sql="select * from studenttable where username='saravanan'";

$calname=array();
$i=0;
mysql_query($sql);
while($rs=mysql_fetch_field($result))
{
         $colname[$i]=$rs->name;
         $i++;


}
$_SESSION['subject']=$calname;
?>


in the next page i print the session variable using 


<?php
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['subject'];
?>

but i am getting "Array"only as output.
how to print the all value of array what i stored into it already?
```

Answer (score 8):

Of course you're only getting `Array` as output.. you're attempting to convert an array to a string without the applicable function for doing so.

If you want to print the full array, as a string, try [`print_r($array);`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php).

Further, you can of course join the array together using a string, using [`implode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php).. and last but not least, be sure to access the individual pieces of the array, should you want them, with their keys:

```
echo $_SESSION['subject']['somekeyhere'];
```

However, it would also appear that from your code, you actually have a few typos that would prevent you from getting the data you need: `$calname` versus the `$colname` variable you have in your while loop.. leaves it as an empty array in your session.

**UPDATE 1:**

Another way to print the entire array.. or rather, echo out each individual value:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    echo $value . "<br />";
}
```

**Off topic:**

I would not recommend using `mysql_*` functions to write new code.  They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/q0gwD). See the [red box](http://goo.gl/OWwr2)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/orrj0) and use either [PDO](http://goo.gl/TD3xh) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/YXyWL) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/b2ATO). Also see [Why shouldn't I use mysql functions in PHP?](http://goo.gl/J5jAo)

Example of your above code using PDO instead(with typos fixed as well):

```
try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=cse", "root", "");
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error!  Could not connect to database: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("select * from studenttable where username=:username");
$stmt->bindValue(":username","saravanan");
$stmt->execute();

$calname = array();
$i = 0;
while ($rs = $stmt->fetch()) {
     $calname[$i]=$rs['name'];
     $i++;
}
$_SESSION['subject']=$calname;
```

Comment: <?php
session_start();
 print_r($_SESSION['sub'])
 //print_r($sub);

?>  i tried like that sir but again getting Array(i=>Lab3) which is my last field name in my table. can u give me one example to print that entire array

Comment: @Saravanan Not exactly.  Put the semi-colon before the comment, and .. Yes, assuming 'sub' is your new array key. I was simply going by the code you provided.

Comment: @Saravanan That is your entire array.  You have a typo preventing `$calname` from getting filled.  However I will give you a foreach example.

Comment: thank you sir. i am expecting your answer.it will be more useful if you give soon sir

Comment: @Saravanan .. Did I not already answer your question?  See the text under the heading 'update 1'.

Answer (score 4):

Try adding with `<pre>` tag to get $_SESSION in more clearer view.

```
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($_SESSION);
    echo '</pre>';
```